# How do I align a title to the center of a video background in CSS3/HTML5?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I want to place my title at the center of the video background.
can you help please?
I know how to place it using position:absolute but I am not sure that this is a correct solution!
Here is my css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#bg {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
}

#h-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

and this is html!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Website Layout</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">

    <video id="bg" src="public/media/test.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
    <div id="h-content">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Help me please!
I need to do that task without any frameworks or libraries like bootstrap, ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` is the best bet for you, try this snippet.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#bg {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative
}

#h-content {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

    <video id="bg" src="public/media/test.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
    <div id="h-content">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```